# Swift - how to stop image change during scrolling in UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using `collectionview` to display downloaded URL-identified image. This is my code:

```
var urlArray = ["url1", "url2", ..., "urln"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell, for: indexPath) as? MyCell
       cell.objectImageView.downloadedFrom(link: urlArray[indexPath.row], contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)
}
```

This is my extension code that asynchronously downloads image:

```
func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
}

func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
    downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
}
```

When I scroll the `collectionview` the image in each cell is changing continuously. I've tried to fix it by setting the `imageview` to `nil` before it loads in `cellForItemAt` method:

```
cell.objectImageView.image = nil
cell.objectImageView.downloadedFrom(link: urlArray[indexPath.row], contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)
```

But it does not work. How to solve this issue?

Comment: From your code it's clear you want to load an image respective to the cell but your problem might be cell reuse. So could you elaborate on what you mean by `changing continuously`? Why do you want to set the image to nil?

Comment: Changing continously in my problem is the image in each cell when scroll it will change to another image in urlArray with wrong position in collectionview. I think if set the image to nil it will clear the imageView and redownload the image to set the correct image to the cell.

Comment: Setting `nil` won't help completely. It's mainly a cell reuse problem. The image download is async which means it will complete at a later time. If you scroll and a cell is reused before the image download completes, it will set the image of previous download call. You need additional info to track this. Let me write something up for you.

Comment: Thanks @staticVoidMan, I'm waiting the solution from you :)

Comment: Why not using SDWebImage for Asynchronous image downloader? Its best for Asynchronous image downloader with cache support as a UIImageView

Comment: @DucPhan does my answer work for you? or you need more? just curious

Comment: @staticVoidMan your answer is worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @DucPhan Great! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `nil` won't help completely. It's mainly a cell reuse problem.

The image download is async which means it will complete at a later time.
If you scroll and a `cell` is reused before the image download completes, it will set the image of the previous download call/s thereby giving rise to your continuous changes that is definitely glitchy.

You will need additional info to track this to basically figure if the completed download task is for the `imageView` or has been reused, in which case another download task will set it.

We can do this in plenty of ways but in the following, we check if the url at the start of the download is same as the url when the download completes.

Something as simple as:

```
func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    /*
     1.
     strUniqueIdentifier_Initial will be the url that caused the download to start.
     A copy of this will be accessible in the closure later.

     Also, we bind this to the imageView for case handling in the closure.
     */
    let strUniqueIdentifier_Initial = url.absoluteString
    self.accessibilityLabel = strUniqueIdentifier_Initial

    contentMode = mode
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }

        /*
         2.
         strUniqueIdentifier_Initial is a copy of the url from the start of the function

         strUniqueIdentifier_Current is the url of the current imageView as we use self
          so if the imageView is reused, this method will be called on it again and at
          that time it it's binded url string will be for the latest download call

         If there's mismatch then the imageView was reused
         */
        let strUniqueIdentifier_Current = self.accessibilityLabel
        if strUniqueIdentifier_Initial != strUniqueIdentifier_Current {
            //previous download task so ignore
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.image = image
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

---

*You can optimize the logic to cancel previous download but this is a basic solution to your core problem.*

Comment: I was facing the same problem and your answer worked. In addition, I'd like to know other ways of tackling this problem as you mentioned that you are aware of other ways or at least provide me with any links I can refer to.  Thanks.

Comment: @BandiA. Glad to help. Here, the basic idea is to ensure that the completed download task is still valid for the cell/imageView. If it's reused for another download task then the previous one should be cancelled or ignored.

Comment: @BandiA. In this example, we use `self.accessibilityLabel` as a hack to store some information in the `imageView` instance so we don't subclass it. A small price to pay unless your app is serious about the accessibility label on this image.

Comment: @BandiA. A better way would be to subclass `UIImageView` and have your own variable to remember the url and maybe even keep a reference of the download request so you may cancel the request to save bandwidth.

Comment: @BandiA. Or... you could modify `downloadedFrom(url:contentMode:)` to have a completion handler like so: `downloadedFrom(url: URL, _ completion: @escaping (UIImage?)->Void) -> DataTask`. The returned `DataTask` can be stored in the cell and if this cell is reused then either pause/cancel the `DataTask` before starting a new one. Also in the completion closure you eventually determine whether the image should be set or not. This way no need for the `self.accessibilityLabel` hack nor subclassing.